Huge delay in Notifications sent to a combination of topics via Firebase Cloud Messaging API (FCM)
We are using Firebase Cloud Messaging API to send Push Notifications to app users.
Since around May 29th 2024 we're experiencing huge delays when sending Notifications to more than one topic. And by huge I mean HOURS of delay.
Usually we send one or more Push Notfication every 5 min to different groups of people, depending on their topic subscriptions, but we use a combination of two topics for each message, so i.e.
"condition": "'Topic A' in topics && 'Topic B' in topics"

This works fine, unless after a while a delay starts building up and the messages are delivered later and later. We have seen delays of 8 hours and more.
This is only a problem when using a combination of topics. So when you send a message just to "Topic A" it is delivered immediately, while a message to condition Topic A && Topic B is delayed.
We are by far not reaching any usage limits. This behaviour is reproducable with just a few hundred request to the FCM API spread over a few hours, i.e 700 Request in 6 hours built up a delay of about an hour.
As I mentioned before, this started around May 29th 2024. Before that it was running just fine for years.
Has anyone an idea, what is going on or has anybody expierienced the same issue?
Edit: I should mention, there are no errors. The requests to the FCM API come back fine with 200

I am facing the exact same thing! started around the same date. The only difference I use OR condition (topic_1 || topic_2).
I contacted firebase support with no help from their side on this issue.
Like you I have been using the service for years with no issues.
One suggestion the firebase support suggested and I am trying now, is to unsubscribe stale tokens from topics. I am trying this now but its going to take some time as I did not have an implementation before to clean stale tokens from topics.
They have a serious issue with targeting topics, and they don't want to admit it.

@Kash Good to know, that I am not alone. I am trying to unsubscribe as many tokens from topics as well...
I agree, they have a serious issue there.

I finished unsubscribing a large number of stale tokens, its a good practice to do. But sadly it didn't fix my issue. Only maybe a slight improvement to the delay.

@Kash I don't have high hopes for this either. But how many are "a large number" in your case? Are we talking thousands? Millions?

I unsubscribed 600k tokens.

I've recently encountered the same issue. Have you discovered anything new or found any possible workarounds?

Am joining the club!
